# MD5 Cracker not working python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, md5, python-3.5

```
md = input("MD5 Hash: ")
if len(md) != 32:
    print("Don't MD5 Hash.")
else:
    liste = input("Wordlist: ")
    ac = open(liste).readlines()
    for new in ac:
        hs = hashlib.md5(new.encode()).hexdigest()
        if hs == md:
            print("MD5 HASH CRACKED : ", new)

    print("Sorry :( Don't Cracked.")
```

executing by not working.
Wordlist:

```
sadasda
asdasda
sdasd
as
da
sdasd
asd
ahmet
asdasf
knknkjnbhb
klasda
```

output:

```
MD5 Hash: cdb5efc9c72196c1bd8b7a594b46b44f
Wordlist: md.txt
Sorry :( Don't Cracked.
```

where did the mistake? I can't see. but wordlist if only:

```
ahmet
```

output:

```
MD5 Hash: cdb5efc9c72196c1bd8b7a594b46b44f
Wordlist: md.txt
MD5 HASH CRACKED :  ahmet
Sorry :( Don't Cracked.
```

Answer (score 2):

The lines from your file include a newline. That newline is significant:

```
>>> from hashlib import md5
>>> md5(b'ahmet').hexdigest()
'cdb5efc9c72196c1bd8b7a594b46b44f'
>>> md5(b'ahmet\n').hexdigest()
'ac5bd810592f14278b5e06fc20d88c23'
```

Remove the newline first:

```
hs = hashlib.md5(new.rstrip('\n').encode()).hexdigest()
```

Rather than have Python decode your file lines, then encode again, just open the file in binary mode. You can loop over the file directly, no need to call `fileobj.readlines()` here:

```
with open(liste, 'rb') as ac:
    for line in ac:
        line = line.rstrip(b'\n')
        hs = hashlib.md5(line).hexdigest()
        if hs == md:
            print("MD5 HASH CRACKED : ", line.decode('utf8'))
```

I've added decoding of the line too, for printing.

Comment: @Ahmet: you are still encoding. Remove the `.encode()` call.

Comment: @Ahmet: there was actually also an error in my code; I forgot to pass in a `bytes` object to `bytes.rstrip()`. Corrected now.

Comment: sory not working.. Python version 3.5.2. method did not work and code:  liste = input("Wordlist: ")
            with open(liste, 'rb') as ac:
                for line in ac:
                    hs = hashlib.md5(line.bytes.rstrip('\n')).hexdigest()
                    if hs == md:
                        print("MD5 HASH CRACKED : ", line)

Comment: @Ahmet: where do you get the `.bytes` attribute from? That's not in my answer.